# What are the open subsets in $[0,1)$?

Tags: general-topology

What will be the open subset in $U=[0,1)$?

I am confused that what will be the open set in this interval because it in itself is not open nor closed ,will the open set be of the form$[0,1/2)$ or $(1/4,1/2)$.

Comment: You'll have to provide more context. Are you talking about a subspace topology?

Comment: can't it be thought of in general @AlexisOlson

Comment: No. Different topologies have different open sets. What topology are you talking about?

Comment: You should *really* know the definition of a topology before asking questions about open sets.

Comment: I read topology but forgot its results ,I need to revise them @Danu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are speaking of the subspace topology of $[0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then the open sets in $U$ are of the form $V\cap [0,1)$ where $V$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. For example, $V=(0,1/2)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, hence $(0,1/2)\cap[0,1)= (0,1/2)$ is open in $U$.

Comment: Or even $(-1/2,1/2)\cap U=[0,1/2)$ is open in $U$.